# How to calculate the distance between a random point in a dataset and a center for the kohonen algorithm?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, self-organizing-maps

I'm trying to calculate the distance between a random datapoint in the dataset and the center for the centroid. However, I get an error.

```
dist= math.sqrt((W[k][0]-dataset[0])**2 + (W[k][1]-dataset[1]**2))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import math
a1 = np.random.randn(250,2)
c1 = (0,0)
arr1 = a1 + (0,0)
a2 = np.random.randn(250,2)
arr2= a2 + [10,10]
c2 = (10,10)
a3 = np.random.randn(250,2)
arr3 = a3 + (0,10)
c3 = (0,10)
a4 = np.random.randn(250,2)
arr4 = a4 + (10,0)
c4 = (10,0)
alpha = 0.1
W = [[0,0],[0,10],[10,0],[10,10]]
dataset = [arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4]
for i in range(100):
    d_min = 999999
    for j in range(250):
        for k in range(4):
            dist= math.sqrt((W[k][0]-dataset[0])**2 + (W[k][1]-dataset[1]**2))
            if dist>d_min:
                d_min = dist
                k_min = k
        W[:,k_min] = W[:,k_min]*(1-alpha) + alpha*dataset[i]
    alpha = 0.5*alpha
```

Comment: `math.sqrt` doesn't like non-scalar inputs. Compare `math.sqrt(np.array([1, 2,3]))` and `math.sqrt(np.array([1]))`. Use `np.sqrt` instead to apply the operation to all elements, but then you'll have a problem at `if dist > min`. How are you supposed to resolve that? You also do `for i in range(100): dataset[i]`, but dataset has only 4 elements.

Comment: So how would I fix this?

Comment: You should explain what your code is supposed to do in more detail. We can only guess what your intentions are and when you've coded the wrong behaviour, it's even harder to deduce that. When I see you're comparing a whole array to a minimum value, one interpretation is you want to get the minimum value of that array and compare that to `d_min`. What are `arr1` and `arr2`? Why `(W[k][0]-dataset[0])**2 + (W[k][1]-dataset[1]**2)`? Why is `i` going up to 100?

Comment: Because we are trying to do 100 iterations

Comment: In what way is `dataset` linked to your iterations? It contains 4 elements. Your program, assuming everything else is taken care of, is going to choke on iteration 4. Do you have some `arr100` hanging around you haven't told us of?

Comment: Because we're doing it 100 times? even when I change the variable for the iteration, it still doesn't work